# Is there a way to generate geofences using open street map on android?

Tags: android, push-notification, openstreetmap, osmdroid, android-geofence

I want to create a simple map app that sends push notifications whenever the geolocation of a device enters a geofence. I've been trying to look for a way to display geofences on osmdroid. What I keep seeing though are Google Map examples. However, I'm not using Google Maps. Do I still need to use Google related implementations (GoogleApiClient, etc.) or is there a way to generate the geofences without google? How about listening to geofence transitions (entering and exiting a geofence) then sending push notifications?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

Comment: Yes I have. But I get confused as to where those code snippets belong to my code. For example, after adding :<service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"/> to manifest, what does  GeofenceTransitionsIntentService contain? @RodrigoE.

Comment: ^That's just one example of how I get confused about the documentation. I hope there are samples online I can follow, since I'm very new to android @RodrigoE.

Comment: The documentation is actually quite good in this case. E.g. the  GeofenceTransitionIntentService is described just a little bit lower: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#HandleGeofenceTransitions

Comment: If you are new to Android, you'll meet a lot of concepts and things you will not understand. Android platform is complex and has a lot of legacy. And geolocation is also not one of the easiest parts. Just dont' give up so easily and try to read the whole documentation and maybe a couple of times.

Answer (score 5):

The most important thing to understand is that GeoFencing is not related to maps at all. Google presents it as part of their Map API because it's the same domain and it makes sense from that point of view.

But technically it's just this:

1. Watch the position of the device using location services in time
2. Compare the location with a set of "geofences" (let's assume
   those are just points + distance).
3. If the location hits the geofence, do something - e.g. display a notification.

Osmdroid offers you a way how to display graphical maps in the app and some overlays over those maps. There are some extensions which allow you to incorporate other things (e.g. current location of the device, routing) but most of the time they are just things you want to primarily display on the map. If you want just geofencing, you don't need to use Osmdroid at all. If you want a map in your app, you can choose to use the Osmdroid library and implement geofencing independently.

Regarding the implementation of goefencing: technically you could do it without google.

**1) Observing the location**

You could use [LocationManager and requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies) and watch the position of the device by yourself. If you expect your application to be on foreground when the geofencing happens, this should be quite easy. But if you need to watch the device's location when your app is on background, it gets tricky. Google is limiting capabilities of applications to perform things on background with every release and they do it for a good reason - battery.

The suggested approach in such case (well, actually, google suggests this approach for every case, where you need to work with the location of the device) is to use [a FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) which is part of Google Play Services library. This has some consequences (it will work only on devices with Google Play Store installed, but also saves battery and resources).

**2) Having a list of geofences and comparing gathered location with them**

This is easy and there are several ways how to implement such functionality. If you limit your definition of "geofence" just to maximal distance from a given point, it's also easy to implement the piec of code which is testing if a location is in a geofence or not - you would just compute distance to the center of the geofence and compare it with its diameter.

**3) Show notification**

[Showing notification is easy on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification). You don't even need push notifications, they would make no sense in this case. The app knows that it wants to display a notification so there's no reason to involve some server in the cloud which would push the notification to the device.

**Should you use the implementation from Google?**

Google implements most of this for you and provides an API you can easily use. So if you don't have any reason to avoid google's implementation I would suggest to use it. Their implementation should be internally the same as I described above and there are no API calls to (potentially) paid API involved.

The API is a part of the Google Play Services Library - in the same way as the FusedLocationProvider API I mentioned earlier. So, If you chose to do your own implementation but decided to use a FusedLocationProvider, you would have all the consequences of using google play services library but also more code to write and more opportunities to make mistakes. Such approach just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Long story short: google-server know where an android device is and can send a notification to the android client when a device leaves or enters a geofence area. Without google you have to implement this on your own in android-client-code

Comment: @k3b Almost, only there doesn't have to be any server involved (and most likely isn't). The google service/library on the device and sends an intent to your app locally. The app decides what to do with it (e.g. it can display a notification). No push/GCM is involved here.